# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Importing solution with too many attributes

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

Here is my problem. I have a crm 4 organization that needs to be converted to crm 2011. That has been done and it has been imported as a crm 2011. I have a dev crm 2011 that I have been making form changes to and have been customizing my sales process and screens. I am trying to import the dev crm solution into the newly converted crm 4 organization but I am getting this error:

> Inner Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Attribute new_welcomepacketsentbyname cannot be created because we have hit a maximum number of attributes allowed for an entity (1000). Entity id: 70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84

I understand the limit and I will have to reduce the number of attributes. Here are my questions:

1. Do I change it in the crm 4 organization? Do I change my imported solution?
2. How do I know how many I have to reduce it by?
3. And how do I know what entity to do it in? How do I find the entity with the id: 70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84?

Answer (score 1):

Conversions are tricky because you typically need to do a conversion of the 4.0 again at go-live to get the latest data.

1. Because of the above reason, I would recommend making the changes in the CRM 4 org, so you don't run into issues during the go-live conversion.
2. select * from MetadataSchema.Attribute a where a.EntityId = 'guid'
3. select * from MetadataSchema.Entity where EntityId = 'guid'